# DataFrame need to get permutations (pyspark)

Tags: python, azure, azure-synapse

so I'm farily new to the Azure Synapse/Notebooks env. I have a Dataframe with an array of lines and I want to create a new dataframe with the combinations between a specific prop of the struct inside. Not sure how to proceed. All examples I find use a simple array of numbers.

[struct inside array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kL5LQ.png)

Thanks in advance to anyone who replies

Answer (score 0):

The below code may work for you to create the required schema:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
schema= StructType([StructField("lines",ArrayType(
    StructType(
        [
            StructField("courseID", StringType(),True),
            StructField("description", StringType(),True),
            StructField("displayRecordId", StringType(),True),
            StructField("menuId", StringType(),True),
            StructField("menuItemId", StringType(),True),
            StructField("minimumCustomerAge", LongType(),True),
            StructField("modifiers", StringType(),True),
            StructField("name", StringType(),True),
            StructField("portionTypeId", StringType(),True),
            StructField("price", DoubleType(),True)
        ]),True),True)
    ])

df=spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data),schema=schema)
df.printSchema()
```

The data in the above is a dummy data.

This is Output of above code for your Reference:
[image]

Please refer this [link](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-arraytype-column-with-examples/) to learn more about the `ArrayType` in Pyspark.